# $P^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right)$ and $P^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right) \Rightarrow P=Q$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $a,b \in {\Bbb C}$ with $a \neq b$  and $P,Q\in{\Bbb C}[X]$. We assume that 
>   $$P^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right) \text{ and }P^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right).$$
>   Prove that $P=Q$.

My idea: I note 
$$P^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{a\}\right) = \{\alpha_i \mid 1 \le i \le p\}$$
and 
$$P^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right)=Q^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right) = \{\beta_i \mid 1 \le i \le q\}$$

Note : $\{\alpha_i \mid 1 \le i \le p\} \cap \{\beta_i \mid 1 \le i \le q\} = \emptyset$ because $a \neq b$.

The $\alpha_i$ are roots of $P-a$ and $Q-a$. The $\beta_i$ are roots of $P-b$ and $Q-b$.

I can say that all the $\alpha_i$ and the $\beta_i$ are roots of the difference $P-Q$.

I don't know what to do with all this ?
Any hints ?